# Pull the limit inside the infinit serie in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: U \mapsto \Bbb C$ a holomorphic function and $U$ an open set of the complex plane. We have
$$f(z)=(z-z_0)^m\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k+m}(z-z_0)^k$$
with $m\geq 1$. In my course, it is written that the right hand side converges on some ball $B_r(z_0)$ thus :
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k+m}(z-z_0)^k=a_m$$
I don't understand why we can put the limit inside the infinit serie... Is it a result from complex analysis ?

Comment: In general, if $f_n:D\subseteq\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ and $z_0\in\overline{D}$ are such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n$ converges uniformly on $D$ and each $\lim_{z\to z_0} f_n(z)$ converges, then we always have $$\lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lim_{z\to z_0}f_n(z).$$ Now, if a power series has radius of convergence $R$ at $z_0$, then that power series converges uniformly on the closed ball $\overline{B_r(z_0)}$ for any $0<r<R$, so we can apply the above general result.

Comment: Thank you ! This is clear !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k$ converges on some disk centered at $z_0$; then its sum is continuous function. And the value that that function takes at $z_0$ is $b_0$. Therefore,$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k=b_0.$$

Comment: Why do you mean by its sum ?

Comment: I mean the sum of the power series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k$.

Comment: So you mean $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k=g(z)$ is a continuous function if the power serie converges ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.